how to set up/configure an aws opensearch index?
I created an aws opensearch instance, which i assume is basically an aws version of elastic search. I also created an index within the instance (sample below) . the index, will have few fields along with a vector field of dimension 1024 and will hold text embeddings. I want to do a vector search based on cosine similarity. my question is do i have to set up/configure any parameters or configuration for cosine similarity specifically, when creating an index ?
PUT my_index{ 
  "settings": { 
      "index.knn": true
  },
  "mappings":{
      "properties":{
            "my_vector": {
                 "type": "knn_vector", 
                 "dimension" : 512
            }
       }
  } 
}

